# Using sum inside a case or decode statement in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I tried looking for a clue but did not get a satisfying answer anywhere.

My problem is I have a huge select statement with almost half of the columns coming out of a subquery and in these subqueries I have to check a lot of things.

I know oracle is strict when it comes to aggregate functions but when I tried something like this in one of the subqueries, I got the ouptut as expected:

```
SELECT DECODE(NVL(SUM(Qty1),0),0,SUM(Qty2),SUM(Qty1))
FROM test_v
WHERE item_no    = 1234567;
```

But strangely when I modified it to this:

```
SELECT 
DECODE(FLAG,1,SUM(Qty2),SUM(Qty1))
FROM test_v
WHERE item_no    = 1234567;
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 8`
```

Why is it giving different results in two almost similar queries. I know it can be resolved by using a `GROUP BY` but how can I decide on the `GROUP BY` clause when I am not getting any other columns in the output.

I also went on to try this with a `CASE` statement like this, but no use:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN flag = 1 THEN
SUM(Qty2)
WHEN flag = 0 THEN
SUM(Qty1)
END Qty
FROM test_v
WHERE item_no    = 1234567;
```

I still get the same error.

I know I could override this by using another subquery for calculating the SUM but that would be like generations of subqueries living inside a select which I don't want for aesthetic, performance and personal reasons with over use of subqueries.

Any ideas why the first one works and this doesn't??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the query producing the error:

```
SELECT DECODE(FLAG, 1, SUM(Qty2), SUM(Qty1))
FROM test_v
WHERE item_no    = 1234567;
```

This is an aggregation query.  Without a `group by`, only one group is in the result set, summarizing all the data.

The problem is that `flag` is not in an aggregation function.  Which value should be used?  There is one on each row.  That is why SQL (in general) requires that all expressions in an aggregation query need to be aggregation functions, except for columns mentioned in the `group by`.

The following would work:

```
SELECT DECODE(MAX(FLAG), 1, SUM(Qty2), SUM(Qty1))
FROM test_v
WHERE item_no    = 1234567;
```

Note:  I'm using `decode()` only because it is in your sample query.  You should learn to use `case`.

Comment: Whoa!! This thing works! :) :) And point noted Sir..Will use the `case` statement instead of decode!! Thanks for sharing such an awesome trick so quickly! :)

Comment: @Neels: If you consider this a trick, you should *really* read on aggregation in SQL. Gordon simply showed you *one* way to get the statement *syntactically* right. Does this really happen to be exactly the query that you were looking for? Have you even understood how Gordon's query works?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Well, the aggregation used here works for my case(obviously I cant show my entire code to prove that I understand). And its not a rocket science to understand what is happening in Gordon's query. Don't think I was wrong on the syntax side, just missed to use the correct aggregation! And I would still call it a trick because without impacting the result at all, this brings out the solution.

Comment: @Neels: As Gordon said, which record's flag shall be used? He showed a way for when at least one record has flag 1 then sum qty2. He could have shown just as well a way for when no record has flag 0. Or when more than 50% of the records have flag 1. Why is there even a flag in each record, when you don't care about the single values (as in: for every record flagged 1 sum qty2, for the others sum qty1)? As this happens to be the right solution for you, okay. But when you took this to be a trick, it seemed you might not have understood what is happening and what other options there are. Sorry.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Okay.. just so that you know, my actual query is something like `SELECT CASE
   WHEN max(a.flag) = 1 THEN
   SUM(a.qty2)
   WHEN max(a.flag) = 0 THEN
decode(nvl(sum(a.qty1),0),0,sum(a.qty2),sum(a.qty1))
   END qty FROM test_v
WHERE item_no    = 1234567 AND flag= i_flag` This `i_flag` gets dynamically passed into this query. This might not be the bestest solution, but I know whats happening! :)